# Convert curl command to requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

How would I convert the following curl command:

```
curl -L -k -H "X-Apple-Store-Front: 143441" -H "X-Apple-Tz: 3600"
     -A "iTunes/9.2.1 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.5.8) AppleWebKit/533.16"
     "https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewMultiRoom?cc=us&fcId=363484947"
```

Into the corresponding `requests` call?

Comment: Try https://curlconverter.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import requests

url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewMultiRoom?cc=us&fcId=363484947'
headers = {
    'X-Apple-Store-Front': '143441-1,12',
    'X-Apple-Tz': '3600',
}

requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: You probably want to split off the arguments from the URI, and pass the arguments as [`params`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) (i.e. `params={'cc': 'us', 'fcId': ...}`)